# clang's -fcatch-undefined-behavior not working as advertised

Tags: c++, c, clang, undefined-behavior

I built the 3.1 release of llvm/compiler-rt/clang, and I'm trying to see if -fcatch-undefined-behavior really does anything. So far, no luck. E.g. I compile and run

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int* x = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    printf("%d\n", x[20]);
    return 0;
}
```

with

```
$ /usr/local/bin/clang -fcatch-undefined-behavior undef_test.c && ./a.out
0
```

Am I missing something really simple?

Comment: Yes, you are missing that catching /all/ undefined behaviour is an incredibly hard problem, too hard for a compiler to implement.

Comment: -faddress-sanitizer should catch this, as should valgrind.

Comment: Thanks, Ambroz. This was most helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: `x` is not an array.

From the [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html):

> **-fcatch-undefined-behavior**: Turn on runtime code generation to check for undefined behavior. This option, which defaults to off, controls whether or not Clang adds runtime checks for undefined runtime behavior. If a check fails, `__builtin_trap()` is used to indicate failure. The checks are:
>
> - Subscripting where the static type of one operand is a variable which is decayed from an array type and the other operand is greater than the size of the array or less than zero.
> - Shift operators where the amount shifted is greater or equal to the promoted bit-width of the left-hand-side or less than zero.
> - If control flow reaches __builtin_unreachable.
> - When llvm implements more __builtin_object_size support, reads and writes for objects that __builtin_object_size indicates we aren't accessing valid memory. Bit-fields and vectors are not yet checked.

I suppose you wanted to test the subscripting check, unfortunately you did not build an array: you built an area of memory (from `malloc`) and then chose to interpret it as an array; but from the point of view of the compiler it is just a chunk of memory (remember than the return type of `malloc` is `void*`).

You could probably test this behavior with:

```
int main() {
    int x[10] = {};
    printf("%d\n", x[20]);
}
```

Otherwise, for a specific memory issues tracker, you should look into the Address Sanitizer plugin.

Comment: This appears to trigger a warning by clang whether or not `-fcatch-undefined-behaviour` is specified.

Comment: @detly: `-fcatch-undefined-behavior` is a code generation option, which is unrelated to warnings; instead it will insert runtime assertions and crash the program (reliably) should any of those assertions be violated. Of course, it is better to trust the warning and act as soon as the compilation start. Note also that `-fcatch-undefined-behavior` is now deprecated and you should be using `-fsanitize` to activate the various address/memory/thread/undefined sanitizers (and bear in mind that some of them are incompatible with one another).

Answer (score 1):

`-fcatch-undefined-behavior` doesn't handle random pointer dereferences. To handle this case, the compiler would have to store the size of the pointed data alongside the pointer and pass that size in every function call. That would be incompatible with the existing ABI and would require to recompile all the libraries your program link to.

You may argue that `malloc` is a well-known function and the compiler could just assume the returned pointer points to an array of the requested size.

But you would be forgetting that `malloc` may return `NULL`. If the compiler assumed the pointer isn't `NULL`, it would optimize out any `NULL` checking (quite dangerous). If the compiler assumed the pointer is `NULL` or a pointer to an array of the requested size, that would become a little complicated to manage (and we haven't talk of `free` and `realloc` yet). Moreover any code that dereferences a `malloc`-ated pointer without `NULL` checking would be considered as undefined behavior.

Not to mention that your program may not link to the standard library but to a library that provides a custom implementation of `malloc` with a different semantic.